# UIButton title alignment and multiline support

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibutton

How do I set the title of a `UIButton` to be left-aligned, and how can I show multiple lines of text in a `UIButton`?

Comment: Please update the tags or your question to tell us what technology this is about.

Comment: Looks like iPhone development.

Comment: Raju, you should really accept your answers... thats what makes the system work.

Comment: UILineBreakModeWordWrap working well but UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft is just like center-left not exactly center align like a UILabel

Comment: UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter

Comment: or  [myButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

Comment: Accept one of the anwers below.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers below. The second one has diagrams!

Answer (score 186):

Here's the code to do the UIButton alignment in code too: -

```
[myButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
```

Answer (score 132):

**To set the alignment of a `UIButton`**,  look in the Attributes Inspector in Interface Builder for the button. There's a section called Alignment. Set it to left. Or right, or whatever you want.

[image]

To do it in code, use the [`contentHorizontalAlignment`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/contentHorizontalAlignment) property of `UIControl`. You can set it to any of these properties:

`UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter`
`UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft`
`UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight`
`UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill`

```
[myButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight];
```

None of these options look particularly good (as you can see above), and you might have might have more luck using the `contentEdgeInsets` property of `UIButton` to reposition the content.

**To set a multiline title** on a `UIButton`, [check this forum post](http://unsolicitedfeedback.com/?p=59) which describes changing the button label.

Or you can use this code to quickly make a 2 line button:

```
myButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
myButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
[myButton setTitle:@"Siegfried\nRoy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image]

Raju, don't forget to mark questions as accepted.

Comment: you didn't get it enough to mark some of your questions answered ;-)

Comment: `numberOfLines` works on iOS5, but still need to set `lineBreakMode` for iOS 4.

Comment: Note that when setting the title, it's important to use the message that specifies the UIControlState.  If you just set it like a property, the label won't resize for the new text.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576331/uibutton-label-text-is-being-clipped

Comment: @AndrewCr Just to be clear, I am using `setTitle:forState` in the example above.

Comment: FYI: UITextAlignmentCenter is deprecated in iOS 6 and NSTextAlignmentCenter should now be used instead.

Comment: In Swift `button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Left` worked for me.

Comment: TextAlignment `.leading` has been introduced since then. This might better fit your multiline text. I noticed similar issue with`.right` vs.  `.trailing` textAlignments and found .trailing to be better. Also noticed .trailing worked with RTL languages too.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, you can set the `lineBreakMode` to `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` or `UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap`. This breaks the text into multiple lines if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
    myButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    myButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
    myButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a Paragraph effect you can change the size of title.

[image: For alinea effect]