# UIButton label text is being clipped

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a UIButton built in Interface Builder that has a default label. In Xcode, I'm changing the label text dynamically like so:

```
myButton.titleLabel.text = @"this is the new label";
```

However, when the text updates, the new string is being clipped down to the same size as the original string and ends up looking like:

```
this...label
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should use [setTitle:forState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW7) to change the title of a `UIButton`. If you change the title yourself, the button has no indication that it needs to resize the label – you'd end up having to do something like this:

```
myButton.titleLabel.text = @"this is the new label";
[myButton setNeedsLayout];
```

but I'm not even sure that would work in all cases. Methods like `setTitle:forState:` are provided so that you can provide titles for multiple states without having to update the button manually, and so that the button knows that it needs to be laid out with a new title.

Comment: Absolutely. The proper way to get dynamic button text to resize the button's titleLabel is through the setTitle:forState:

Comment: Or just, btnChooseAnAccount.setTitle(displayName, for: .normal )

Comment: It did not help, but `myButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;` did

Answer (score 33):

Try using the button's setTitle method (rather than setting the title directly on the label). It should force the title label to be resized.

Objective C:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"This is the text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or in Swift:

```
myButton.setTitle("This is the text", for: .normal)
```

Comment: +1 for the perfect answer. I tried all the two alternatives given above. But not could be able to solve my problem except this answer.

Comment: instead the selected best answer, this one worked perfectly for me! +1

Comment: This is the most straightforward and correct . answer.

Answer (score 23):

An alternative solution is to let the UIButton's inner UILabel to shrink the font size, as UILabels can do :

```
button.titlelabel.minimumFontSize = 8.0; // or some more adequate size
self.buttonWithLongTitle.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Comment: that is the only thing that works for me... the button isn't stretched but at least you can see the text

Comment: Note: `minimumFontSize` is now deprecate. Use `minimumScaleFactor` instead. I.e. to completely stop downscaling, using `minimumScaleFactor = 1.0;`

Comment: This is the right answer, in particular adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is the method the OP is looking for.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. In most cases it's an unacceptable compromise to settle for arbitrary font sizes.

Comment: Simply great ;)

Answer (score 10):

Call `sizeToFit` on your button. This will resize the button to fit the text.

Comment: setNeedsLayout didn't helper me but sizeToFit solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If that didn't work you can always determine the string size and adjust the button frame width. In that case you are sure it will fit.

```
// Calculate the size 
CGSize buttonSize = [@"My text.." sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0]
                    constrainedToSize:someSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

// Do whatever you want with the "buttonSize", you can for example adjust your button's frame width
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Solution in Swift 4.2**

```
yourButton.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5 //set whatever you want here to scale
yourButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

> Solution for **Objective C**

```
[yourButton.titleLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:0.5];
[yourButton.titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me while setting my button up programmatically with all other constraints.

```
       yourButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: yourButton.intrinsicContentSize.width).isActive = true
```

You can also add "padding" like so

```
       yourButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Autoresizing mask` if not selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me. What did was sublclassing `UIButton` and re-setting the `frame` of the `titleLabel`:

**Context:** My font was Josefin Sans and it does clipping the top part of "Ñ". I can imagine it could happen with any other text using a different font.

```
open class Button: UIButton {

    open override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        guard let titleLabel = titleLabel else {
            return
        }
        // Play around to get these numbers
        let heightToAdd: CGFloat = 15 
        let widthToAdd: CGFloat = 100

        titleLabel.frame = CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(
              x: titleLabel.frame.origin.x - widthToAdd / 2, 
              y: titleLabel.frame.origin.y - heightToAdd / 2),
            size: CGSize(
              width: titleLabel.frame.width + widthToAdd, 
              height: titleLabel.frame.height + heightToAdd
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Play around with the values `widthToAdd` and `heightToAdd` or make them injectable when setting a new title.

It is not a superb solution, but it was the only think that worked for me.